# what is the best way to read file containing handwritten text along with typed text?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, ocr, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

what is the best way to read pdf file containing handwritten text along with typed text?
Like file started with typed text then some blank spaces are filled with handwritten text followed by typed text again.

Answer (score 0):

May not be totally what you are looking for but you can try converting pdf to images and then put into some models using OCR like [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/). This is not a difficult task then I think OCR is enough instead of using DL.